# Removing object from ArrayList without knowing index

Tags: java

Let's say i have ArrayList of 10 cars and i want to remove car at index 6 from my list. How should my removeCar function looks like if my existing code is:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Car C1 = new Car();
        C1.addCar("audi", 5);
        C1.addCar("porsche", 3);

        C1.removeCar("audi"); // is not working
        
}

public class Car {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    private ArrayList<Car> cars;

    public Car() {
        this.cars = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Car(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void addCar(String name, int age) {
        this.cars.add(new Car(name, age));
    }

    public void removeCar(String name) {
        this.cars.remove(name);
    }

      public ArrayList<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }
}
```

How to change remove method to be able to remove cars from ArrayList by their name?

Comment: It didn't work because your class did not override ` equals` and `hashCode` so the `ArrayList.remove()` method has no way of knowing how to compare objects for equality.

Comment: I just wonder - should this `remove` method delete the _first_ or _all_ cars in the list by the same name?

Comment: @AlexRudenko It removes the first element encountered. To remove all use `removeIf`. In the example above could do `removeIf(car->car.getMake().equalsIgnoreCase("audi"))` to remove all audis from the list.  I would also remove the default constructor and force setting at least a make of the car.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate `cars` using an [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html) and remove the car using the iterator variable if its name matches with the given `name` (i.e. the `name` passed as a parameter to the method).

Do it as follows:

```
public void removeCar(String name) {
    Iterator<Car> car = cars.iterator();
    while (car.hasNext()) {
        if (car.next().name.equals(name)) {
            car.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Another option (which I do not recommend) is to override `equals` and `hashCode` methods just on `name` and then use `List#contains` as shown below:

```
class Car {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    private ArrayList<Car> cars;

    public Car() {
        this.cars = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Car(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Car(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void addCar(String name, int age) {
        this.cars.add(new Car(name, age));
    }

    public void removeCar(String name) {
        Car car = new Car(name);
        if (cars.contains(car)) {
            cars.remove(car);
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<Car> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Car other = (Car) obj;
        return Objects.equals(name, other.name);
    }
}
```

Note that this approach also requires providing a contractor with just `name` as the parameter.

Comment: ok thanks but is it possible to make it without iterator?

Comment: Yes, it's possible but I don't recommend that. I've posted an update for the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove an object from an array list you can just do it by specifying the object. It will remove the first one it comes to.  Or did I misunderstand what you wanted to do?

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
list.add("A");
list.add("B");
list.add("C");
list.add("D");
        
System.out.println(list);
list.remove("C");
System.out.println(list);
```

Prints

```
[A, B, C, D]
[A, B, D]
```

For this to work your class must override `equals` and `hashCode` based on the name of the car.